# Common programming mistakes for Clojure developers to avoid

Tags: clojure

What are some common mistakes made by Clojure developers, and how can we avoid them?

For example; newcomers to Clojure think that the `contains?` function works the same as `java.util.Collection#contains`.  However, `contains?` will only work similarly when used with indexed collections like maps and sets and you're looking for a given key:

```
(contains? {:a 1 :b 2} :b)
;=> true
(contains? {:a 1 :b 2} 2)
;=> false
(contains? #{:a 1 :b 2} :b)
;=> true
```

When used with numerically indexed collections (vectors, arrays) `contains?` **only** checks that the given element is within the valid range of indexes (zero-based):

```
(contains? [1 2 3 4] 4)
;=> false
(contains? [1 2 3 4] 0)
;=> true
```

If given a list, `contains?` will never return true.

Comment: Just FYI, for those Clojure devs looking for **java.util.Collection#contains** type functionality, check out **clojure.contrib.seq-utils/includes?** From the docs: *Usage: (includes? coll x). Returns true if coll contains something equal (with =) to x, in linear time.*

Comment: You seem to have missed the fact that those questions are Community Wiki

Comment: I love how the Perl question just has to be out of step with all the others :)

Comment: For Clojure devs looking for contains, I'd recommend not following rcampbell's advice. seq-utils has long since been deprecated and that function was never useful to begin with. You can use Clojure's `some` function or, better yet, just use `contains` itself. Clojure collections implement `java.util.Collection`. `(.contains [1 2 3] 2) => true`

Answer (score 71):

**Literal Octals**

At one point I was reading in a matrix which used leading zeros to maintain proper rows and columns. Mathematically this is correct, since leading zero obviously don't alter the underlying value. Attempts to define a var with this matrix, however, would fail mysteriously with:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid number: 08
```

which totally baffled me. The reason is that Clojure treats literal integer values with leading zeros as octals, and there is no number 08 in octal.

I should also mention that Clojure supports traditional Java hexadecimal values via the **0x** prefix. You can also use any base between 2 and 36 by using the "base+r+value" notation, such as **2r101010** or **36r16** which are 42 base ten.

---

**Trying to return literals in an [anonymous function literal](http://clojure.org/reader#toc2)**

This works:

```
user> (defn foo [key val]
    {key val})
#'user/foo
user> (foo :a 1)
{:a 1}
```

so I believed this would also work:

```
(#({%1 %2}) :a 1)
```

but it fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args passed to: PersistentArrayMap
```

because the **#()** reader macro gets expanded to

```
(fn [%1 %2] ({%1 %2}))
```

with the map literal wrapped in parenthesis. Since it's the first element, it's treated as a function (which a literal map actually is), but no required arguments (such as a key) are provided. In summary, the anonymous function literal does **not** expand to

```
(fn [%1 %2] {%1 %2})  ; notice the lack of parenthesis
```

and so you can't have any literal value ([], :a, 4, %) as the body of the anonymous function.

Two solutions have been given in the comments. **Brian Carper** suggests using sequence implementation constructors (array-map, hash-set, vector) like so:

```
(#(array-map %1 %2) :a 1)
```

while **Dan** shows that you can use the [identity](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/identity) function to unwrap the outer parenthesis:

```
(#(identity {%1 %2}) :a 1)
```

Brian's suggestion actually brings me to my next mistake...

---

**Thinking that [hash-map](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/hash-map) or [array-map](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/array-map) determine the *unchanging* concrete map implementation**

Consider the following:

```
user> (class (hash-map))
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap
user> (class (hash-map :a 1))
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
user> (class (assoc (apply array-map (range 2000)) :a :1))
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

While you generally won't have to worry about the concrete implementation of a Clojure map, you should know that functions which grow a map - like **assoc** or **conj** - can take a *PersistentArrayMap* and return a *PersistentHashMap*, which performs faster for larger maps.

---

**Using a function as the recursion point rather than a [loop](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc11) to provide initial bindings**

When I started out, I wrote a lot of functions like this:

```
; Project Euler #3
(defn p3 
  ([] (p3 775147 600851475143 3))
  ([i n times]
    (if (and (divides? i n) (fast-prime? i times)) i
      (recur (dec i) n times))))
```

When in fact [loop](http://clojure.org/special_forms#toc11) would have been more concise and idiomatic for this particular function:

```
; Elapsed time: 387 msecs
(defn p3 [] {:post [(= % 6857)]}
  (loop [i 775147 n 600851475143 times 3]
    (if (and (divides? i n) (fast-prime? i times)) i
      (recur (dec i) n times))))
```

Notice that I replaced the empty argument, "default constructor" function body **(p3 775147 600851475143 3)** with a loop + initial binding. The **recur** now rebinds the loop bindings (instead of the fn parameters) and jumps back to the recursion point (loop, instead of fn).

---

**Referencing "phantom" vars**

I'm speaking about the type of var you might define using the REPL - during your exploratory programming - then unknowingly reference in your source. Everything works fine until you reload the namespace (perhaps by closing your editor) and later discover a bunch of unbound symbols referenced throughout your code. This also happens frequently when you're refactoring, moving a var from one namespace to another.

---

**Treating the for [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) like an imperative for loop**

Essentially you're creating a lazy list based on existing lists rather than simply performing a controlled loop. Clojure's [doseq](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq) is actually more analogous to imperative foreach looping constructs.

One example of how they're different is the ability to filter which elements they iterate over using arbitrary predicates:

```
user> (for [n '(1 2 3 4) :when (even? n)] n)
(2 4)

user> (for [n '(4 3 2 1) :while (even? n)] n)
(4)
```

Another way they're different is that they can operate on infinite lazy sequences:

```
user> (take 5 (for [x (iterate inc 0) :when (> (* x x) 3)] (* 2 x)))
(4 6 8 10 12)
```

They also can handle more than one binding expression, iterating over the rightmost expression first and working its way left:

```
user> (for [x '(1 2 3) y '(\a \b \c)] (str x y))
("1a" "1b" "1c" "2a" "2b" "2c" "3a" "3b" "3c")
```

There's also no **break** or **continue** to exit prematurely.

---

**Overuse of structs**

I come from an OOPish background so when I started Clojure my brain was still thinking in terms of objects. I found myself modeling everything as a **struct** because its grouping of "members", however loose, made me feel comfortable. In reality, **structs** should mostly be considered an optimization; Clojure will share the keys and some lookup information to conserve memory. You can further optimize them by defining [accessors](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/accessor) to speed up the key lookup process.

Overall you don't gain anything from using a **struct** over a **map** except for performance, so the added complexity might not be worth it.

---

**Using unsugared BigDecimal constructors**

I needed a lot of [BigDecimals](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and was writing ugly code like this:

```
(let [foo (BigDecimal. "1") bar (BigDecimal. "42.42") baz (BigDecimal. "24.24")]
```

when in fact Clojure supports BigDecimal literals by appending **M** to the number:

```
(= (BigDecimal. "42.42") 42.42M) ; true
```

Using the sugared version cuts out a lot of the bloat. In the comments, **twils** mentioned that you can also use the [bigdec](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/bigdec) and [bigint](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/bigint) functions to be more explicit, yet remain concise.

---

**Using the Java package naming conversions for namespaces**

This isn't actually a mistake per se, but rather something that goes against the idiomatic structure and naming of a typical Clojure project. My first substantial Clojure project had namespace declarations - and corresponding folder structures - like this:

```
(ns com.14clouds.myapp.repository)
```

which bloated up my fully-qualified function references:

```
(com.14clouds.myapp.repository/load-by-name "foo")
```

To complicate things even more, I used a standard [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) directory structure:

```
|-- src/
|   |-- main/
|   |   |-- java/
|   |   |-- clojure/
|   |   |-- resources/
|   |-- test/
...
```

which is more complex than the "standard" Clojure structure of:

```
|-- src/
|-- test/
|-- resources/
```

which is the default of [Leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) projects and [Clojure](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure/) itself.

---

**Maps utilize Java's equals() rather than Clojure's = for key matching**

Originally reported by **chouser** on [IRC](http://irc.freenode.net/#clojure), this usage of Java's **equals()** leads to some unintuitive results:

```
user> (= (int 1) (long 1))
true
user> ({(int 1) :found} (int 1) :not-found)
:found
user> ({(int 1) :found} (long 1) :not-found)
:not-found
```

Since both **Integer** and **Long** instances of 1 are printed the same by default, it can be difficult to detect why your map isn't returning any values. This is especially true when you pass your key through a function which, perhaps unbeknownst to you, returns a long.

It should be noted that using Java's **equals()** instead of Clojure's **=** is essential for maps to conform to the java.util.Map interface.

---

I'm using [Programming Clojure](http://pragprog.com/titles/shcloj/programming-clojure) by Stuart Halloway, [Practical Clojure](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430272317) by Luke VanderHart, and the help of countless Clojure hackers on [IRC](http://irc.freenode.net/#clojure) and the mailing list to help along my answers.

Comment: All of the reader macros have a normal function version.  You could do `(#(hash-set %1 %2) :a 1)` or in this case `(hash-set :a 1)`.

Comment: You could also 'remove' the additional parentheses with identity: (#(identity {%1 %2}) :a 1)

Comment: You could also use `do`: `(#(do {%1 %2}) :a 1)`.

Comment: @Michał - I don't like this solution as much as the previous ones because **do** implies that a side effect is taking place, when in fact this isn't the case here.

Comment: @rrc7cz: Well, in reality, there's no need to use an anonymous function here at all, since using `hash-map` directly (as in `(hash-map :a 1)` or `(map hash-map keys vals)`) is more readable and doesn't imply that something special and as-of-yet unimplemented in a named function is taking place (which the use of `#(...)` does imply, I find). In fact, overusing anonymous fns is a gotcha to think about in itself. :-) OTOH, I sometimes use `do` in super-concise anonymous functions which are side-effect free... It tends to be obvious that they are at a single glance. A matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: @Michał - You're right that it's probably a bad example. I was originally thinking of a basic map case, like `(map #({%1 %2}) [1 2 3] [\a \b \c])`, but I wanted the simplest example possible. I also agree that overusing anonymous fns is a gotcha; you should write up an answer for it. You might mention also that you can't nest anonymous fns.

Comment: Also: (= (bigdec "42.42") 42.42M); true

Comment: You can also use: (#(or {%1 %2}) :a 1)

Answer (score 42):

#### Forgetting to force evaluation of lazy seqs

Lazy seqs aren't evaluated unless you ask them to be evaluated.  You might expect this to print something, but it doesn't.

```
user=> (defn foo [] (map println [:foo :bar]) nil)
#'user/foo
user=> (foo)
nil
```

The `map` is never evaluated, it's silently discarded, because it's lazy.  You have to use one of `doseq`, `dorun`, `doall` etc. to force evaluation of lazy sequences for side-effects.

```
user=> (defn foo [] (doseq [x [:foo :bar]] (println x)) nil)
#'user/foo
user=> (foo)
:foo
:bar
nil
user=> (defn foo [] (dorun (map println [:foo :bar])) nil)
#'user/foo
user=> (foo)
:foo
:bar
nil
```

Using a bare `map` at the REPL kind of looks like it works, but it only works because the REPL forces evaluation of lazy seqs itself.  This can make the bug even harder to notice, because your code works at the REPL and doesn't work from a source file or inside a function.

```
user=> (map println [:foo :bar])
(:foo
:bar
nil nil)
```

Comment: +1. This bit me, but in a more insidious manner: I was evaluating `(map ...)` from within `(binding ...)` and wondering why new binding values  do not apply.

Answer (score 20):

I'm a Clojure noob. More advanced users may have more interesting problems.

#### trying to print infinite lazy sequences.

I knew what I was doing with my lazy sequences, but for debugging purposes I inserted some print/prn/pr calls, temporarily having forgotten what it is I was printing. Funny, why's my PC all hung up?

#### trying to program Clojure imperatively.

There is some temptation to create a whole lot of `ref`s or `atom`s and write code that constantly mucks with their state. This can be done, but it's not a good fit. It may also have poor performance, and rarely benefit from multiple cores.

#### trying to program Clojure 100% functionally.

A flip side to this: Some algorithms really do want a bit of mutable state. Religiously avoiding mutable state at all costs may result in slow or awkward algorithms. It takes judgement and a bit of experience to make the decision.

#### trying to do too much in Java.

Because it's so easy to reach out to Java, it's sometimes tempting to use Clojure as a scripting language wrapper around Java. Certainly you'll need to do exactly this when using Java library functionality, but there's little sense in (e.g.) maintaining data structures in Java, or using Java data types such as collections for which there are good equivalents in Clojure.

Answer (score 13):

**Keeping your head in loops.**
You risk running out of memory if you loop over the elements of a potentially very large, or infinite, lazy sequence while keeping a reference to the first element.

**Forgetting there's no TCO.**
Regular tail-calls consume stack space, and they will overflow if you're not careful. Clojure has `'recur` and `'trampoline` to handle many of the cases where optimized tail-calls would be used in other languages, but these techniques have to be intentionally applied.

**Not-quite-lazy sequences.**
You may build a lazy sequence with `'lazy-seq` or `'lazy-cons` (or by building upon higher level lazy APIs), but if you wrap it in `'vec` or pass it through some other function that realizes the sequence, then it will no longer be lazy. Both the stack and the heap can be overflown by this.

**Putting mutable things in refs.**
You can technically do it, but only the object reference in the ref itself is governed by the STM - not the referred object and its fields (unless they are immutable and point to other refs). So whenever possible, prefer to only immutable objects in refs. Same thing goes for atoms.

Comment: the upcoming development branch goes a long way towards reducing the first item by erasing references to objects in a function once they become locally unreachable.

Answer (score 13):

Lots of things already mentioned. I'll just add one more.

Clojure **if** treats Java Boolean objects always as true even if it's value is false. So if you have a java land function that returns a java Boolean value, make sure you do not check it directly
 `(if java-bool "Yes" "No")` 
but rather 
`(if (boolean java-bool) "Yes" "No")`.

I got burned by this with clojure.contrib.sql library that returns database boolean fields as java Boolean objects.

Comment: Note that `(if java.lang.Boolean/FALSE (println "foo"))` doesn't print foo. `(if (java.lang.Boolean. "false") (println "foo"))` does, though, whereas `(if (boolean (java.lang.Boolean "false")) (println "foo"))` does not... Quite confusing indeed!

Comment: It seems to work as expected in Clojure 1.4.0: (assert (= :false (if Boolean/FALSE :true :false)))

Comment: I also got burned by this one recently when doing (filter :mykey coll) where :mykey's values where Booleans - works as expected with Clojure-created collections, but NOT with deserialized collections, when serialized using default Java serialization - because those Booleans are deserialized as new Boolean(), and sadly (new Boolean(true) != java.lang.Boolean/TRUE)

Comment: Just remember the basic rules of Boolean values in Clojure – `nil` and `false` are false, and everything else is true. A Java `Boolean` is not `nil` and it is not `false` (because it is an object), so the behavior is consistent.

Answer (score 9):

using `loop ... recur` to process sequences when map will do.

```
(defn work [data]
    (do-stuff (first data))
    (recur (rest data)))
```

vs.

```
(map do-stuff data)
```

The map function (in the latest branch) uses chunked sequences and many other optimizations. Also, because this function is frequently run, the Hotspot JIT usually has it optimized and ready to go with out any "warm up time".

Comment: These two versions are actually not equivalent. Your `work` function is equivalent to `(doseq [item data] (do-stuff item))`. (Besides the fact, that loop in work never ends.)

Comment: yes, the first one breaks laziness on its arguments. the resulting seq will have the same values though it no longer be a lazy seq.

Comment: +1! I wrote numerous small recursive functions only to find another day that these all could be generalised by using `map` and/or `reduce`.

Answer (score 5):

**Collection types have different behaviors for some operations:**

```
user=> (conj '(1 2 3) 4)    
(4 1 2 3)                 ;; new element at the front
user=> (conj [1 2 3] 4) 
[1 2 3 4]                 ;; new element at the back

user=> (into '(3 4) (list 5 6 7))
(7 6 5 3 4)
user=> (into [3 4] (list 5 6 7)) 
[3 4 5 6 7]
```

---

Working with strings can be confusing (I still don't quite get them).  Specifically, **strings are not the same as sequences of characters, even though sequence functions work on them:**

```
user=> (filter #(> (int %) 96) "abcdABCDefghEFGH")
(\a \b \c \d \e \f \g \h)
```

To get a string back out, you'd need to do:

```
user=> (apply str (filter #(> (int %) 96) "abcdABCDefghEFGH"))
"abcdefgh"
```

Answer (score 3):

too many parantheses, especially with void java method call inside which results in NPE:

```
public void foo() {}

((.foo))
```

results in NPE from outer parantheses because inner parantheses evaluate to nil.

```
public int bar() { return 5; }

((.bar))
```

results in the easier to debug:

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
  [Thrown class java.lang.ClassCastException]
```